# How can we restrict inheritance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is it possible to restrict inheritance in javascript ? I searched internet about restricting of inheritance in javascript but didn't find any useful information.Can someone explain on this topic of inheritance restriction ? I would like to restrict inheriting properties of my singleton object in other objects.

Comment: What use case do you have for restricting inheritance? It would help if you explain your problem in more depth. In general, "restricting inheritance" is not possible in javascript.

Comment: I got requirement that I need create singleton of object and needs to restrict inheriting singleton object properties in other objects.

Comment: @rpelluru JavaScript doesn't have an equivalent to `sealed`, `final`, etc. attributes. You can hide the constructor, if it has one, with a closure. But, inheritance in JavaScript is based in objects rather than classes, so an instance can always be created with just [`Object.create(singleton)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: What code do you have that "allows" "inheritance" in a way you don't want?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict inheritance in javascript.  If you have a public constructor function that initializes an object, any other object can use it to make a derived object.

You can make many instance variables or even methods private with certain methods of declaration (see [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) for reference) which can reduce the usefulness or capabilities of a derived object though still doesn't prevent it.

Perhaps if you explain what problem you're really trying to solve, we could offer more concrete ideas on how to solve it.

---

OK, now that you've explained that you just want a singleton, then I'd suggest you use a singleton design pattern like this:

```
var Singleton = (function () {

    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
```

The constructor is private (contained within the closure) so it can't be called by other code and the means of getting the object is a function that only ever returns the single instance.  Of course, any properties/methods on an object in JS can be copied, but a singleton like this can keep instance data in the closure if it wants where it cannot be copied.

References:

[Learning Javascript Design Patterns - The Singleton Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript)

[Singleton Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript-singleton-pattern.aspx)

[Javascript Singleton Design pattern](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javascript-singleton-design-pattern/)

[Javascript Design Patterns: Singleton](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/08/08/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got requirement that I need create singleton of object and needs to restrict inheriting singleton object properties in other objects.

Comment: @rpelluru - please edit your question to add this info about a singleton to your question because that makes the question into a whole different question.

Comment: @rpelluru - OK, I've added info to my answer about singletons.